# NodeJs : Any way to bypass querystring.stringify with empty Object?

Tags: node.js, query-string, stringify, superagent

I am working currently on a project that requires to send custom GET HTTP requests.

I am using the default querystring builder : [the Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
```

The problem is for Object (probably also for empty array) such as

```
extendTypes={}
```

is serialiazed as :

```
extendTypes=
```

The expected result :

```
extendTypes={}
```

or its URI encoded version :

```
extendTypes%3D%7B%7D
```

So , how can I ever hope to do that ? If It is impossible with the in-builded module, which one could do what I want.

Here is my full code if you want :

```
function generateGetRequest(dataMap, url) {

    let queryParams = {};
    let uriParams = {};

    for (let [key, value] of dataMap) {

        // if value is an object or an array
        if (value instanceof Object || value instanceof Array) {
            uriParams[key] = value;
        } else {
            // param working for superagent
            queryParams[key] = value;
        }

    }
    let queryParamsUri = querystring.stringify(uriParams);
    console.log(queryParamsUri);
    let finalUrl = url + ( (Object.keys(uriParams).length > 0) ? "?" + queryParamsUri : "");
}
```

Comment: Is your `querystring` an object?

Comment: It is a inbuilded node module : https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Comment: As per the docs, if the querystring contains any empty parameter, it will be coming as `someVar=`. (For eg, `querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' }) ` would return `'foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge='` (look at the `corge` value here).

Comment: Any way to bypass this default ? No sign of this inside documentation

Comment: Unrelated tip: having `instanceof Array` is useless if you are checking `instanceof Object` first, since arrays are instances of `Object`.

Comment: Oups, thanks for marking this useless thing : I have forgotten this XD (Arrays are a special type of objects. The typeof operator in JavaScript returns "object" for arrays.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround , if someone wants to know :

```
let request = require("superagent");

function generateGetRequest(dataMap, url) {

    let queryParams = {};
    let queryParamsUri = "";
    let isFirstParam = true;

    for (let [key, value] of dataMap) {

        // if value is an object or an array
        if (value instanceof Object) {

            // Workaround for empty object or array = https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12234
            queryParamsUri += ((!isFirstParam) ? "&": "") + key + "=" + JSON.stringify(value);
            // for next call
            isFirstParam = false;
        } else {
            // param working for superagent
            queryParams[key] = value;
        }
    }

    let finalUrl = url + ( (!isFirstParam) ? "?" + queryParamsUri : "");
    return request
        .get(finalUrl)
        .query(queryParams);
}
```